# In react how to update state when checkbox is disabled?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

### Situation

I have a semi complex form implemented in react in which ticking certain checkboxes will lead to other checkboxes being enabled/disabled. This all works fine, but if a disabled tickbox was previously ticked then its state remains even though the UI is showing it unticked. For example

[image]

This state is created by first ticking A so B becomes available, ticking B, then unticking A. This leaves a ghost state for tickbox B

## Minimal example

Here is a simplified example of my depentant tick boxes. Note that tickbox B unticks itself in the UI if tickbox A is unticked. But handleToggleTickBoxB is not called when this happens to update the underlying state.

```
const e = React.createElement;

class ReactGameForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            tickBoxA:false,
            tickBoxB:false
        };
    }

    handleToggleTickBoxA = (event) => {

        this.setState({tickBoxA: event.target.checked})
    }

    handleToggleTickBoxB = (event) => {
        this.setState({tickBoxB: event.target.checked})
    }

    render() {
        return <form>
            <div className="form-check">
                <input className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="platformRadios" value="A" id="tickboxA" checked = {this.state.tickBoxA} onChange={event => this.handleToggleTickBoxA(event)} />
                <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="tickboxA">
                    <b>Tick Box A</b>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div className="form-check">
                <input disabled = {!this.state.tickBoxA} className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="B" id="tickboxB" checked = {this.state.tickBoxA && this.state.tickBoxB} onChange={event => this.handleToggleTickBoxB(event)} />
                <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="tickboxB">
                    <b>Tick Box B</b>
                </label>
            </div>
            <p>Tick box A: {this.state.tickBoxA && <span>Ticked</span>}</p>
            <p>Tick box B: {this.state.tickBoxB && <span>Ticked</span>}</p>
        </form>
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    const domContainer = document.querySelector('#react_game_form');
    ReactDOM.render(e(ReactGameForm), domContainer);
})
```

This causes all sorts of complexity further down the line where other bits of UI *think* tickbox B is ticked.

## Question

What is the proper way to ensure that state dependant disabling is propagated so that the state of that tickbox is reflected in the react state

## Notes

In the real example this is a list of libraries which have relatively complex rules as to if they are available. Its not as simple as A -> B. It might be "B requires any 1 of A1 A2 or A3 but must not have A4"

Answer (score 0):

In the end I realised I was doing too much state calculation in the `render()` itself, and moved the equivalent to the "untick tickboxB" into handleToggleTickBoxA itself. Then the state and UI remained in sync.

So my self answer would be that this is what I should have done:

```
const e = React.createElement;

class ReactGameForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            tickBoxA:false,
            tickBoxB:false
        };
    }

    handleToggleTickBoxA = (event) => {

        this.setState({tickBoxA: event.target.checked, tickBoxB: event.target.checked && this.state.tickBoxB })
    }

    handleToggleTickBoxB = (event) => {
        this.setState({tickBoxB: event.target.checked})
    }

    render() {
        return <form>
            <div className="form-check">
                <input className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="platformRadios" value="A" id="tickboxA" checked = {this.state.tickBoxA} onChange={event => this.handleToggleTickBoxA(event)} />
                <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="tickboxA">
                    <b>Tick Box A</b>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div className="form-check">
                <input disabled = {!this.state.tickBoxA} className="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="B" id="tickboxB" checked = {this.state.tickBoxB} onChange={event => this.handleToggleTickBoxB(event)} />
                <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor="tickboxB">
                    <b>Tick Box B</b>
                </label>
            </div>
            <p>Tick box A: {this.state.tickBoxA && <span>Ticked</span>}</p>
            <p>Tick box B: {this.state.tickBoxB && <span>Ticked</span>}</p>
        </form>
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    const domContainer = document.querySelector('#react_game_form');
    ReactDOM.render(e(ReactGameForm), domContainer);
})
```